# Linux ls wrong date format

Tags: ls, date, locale

I try to find why when I do the command `ls` or whatever `ls -la` the column format is wrong with date.

It should be like that:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 johndoe johndoe   55 janv. 26  2011
```

not like that :

```
 drwxr-xr-x  6 neworldc neworldc 4096 ao0  2011 fr/
```

take a look to the date format ??? : `ao0  2011` or like that: `f  3 03:14`

Comment: What's the output of `locale`?

Comment: That's probably because `Août` has an accent and your terminal does not know how to display them with the locale settings you are using.

Answer (score 4):

There is likely a mismatch between the codeset `ls` is told to use and what you terminal emulator think it is.

Try the following commands:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -l

LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF8 ls -l

LC_ALL=fr_FR.ISO-8859-1 ls -l
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and my locale is en_AU. `ls` insists on putting the month first, and that's completely incorrect in my locale. As it happens, if I do `LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF8 ls -l` I get "avr.  16 14:26", which is also wrong for France.