# How can I know the type of each element in the output of ls -l?

Tags: ls, output

I was checking what exactly each field is in the output of `ls -l`. The example in  [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean?newreg=d407c51c023d4d7f9a361adf0fd6d0dd) solves my question. But again I'm wondering what type of each field is. The strings are obvious. But how about the numbers? Like `10`, `2048`, are they integers or strings? Is there any way I can check the type of each field?

Comment: `ls -l` produces a string.  If you feed the output of `ls -l` to bash or awk or another program, how that program interprets the strings is up to it.

Comment: Ok, I was confused because I saw someone read the output using `scanf ("%s, %s, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s, %s, %s， some_variable, some_variable, ...")` Like why the middle one is `%d` instead of `%s`

Comment: `%d` affects how C interprets the string it reads as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text produced by commands in the terminal are text strings.  Viewing raw binary data in the terminal, without converting it to some text representation, generally has a tendency to produce "garbled output" (for example, when running `cat` on a compressed file) and may in some cases even put the terminal in a unusable state.

The numbers in the output of `ls -l` are text strings.

To read text as integers into e.g. a C program, the program would have to read them as text strings and later convert them to integers using e.g. `strtol()`, or use `scanf()` (or equivalent) with the correct format string.

Shell tools that read integers, such as `awk` for example, generally already do this conversion behind the scene according to the rules implemented by the tool.

---

Side note: A C program should not parse the numbers from the output of `ls -l`.  It should call `stat()` or `lstat()` on the files returned by `readdir()`.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs is obligatory here.  But also note that M. Wooledge does not touch upon the fact that dates do not have a stable single form (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332228/) and are in locale-determined formats (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115066/).  That side note should really be a headline.  (-: